# Managed Store Cache not working

Tags: caching, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

My cache block never works, always the http request is made for same values.

```
    <ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="eventIdCachingStrategy" doc:name="Autobulk EventID Caching Strategy" keyGenerationExpression="#[flowVars['ablMapEventToListingParameters']]">
       <managed-store storeName="${xyz.eventid.cache.store.name}" persistent="true" maxEntries="${xyz.eventid.cache.max.entries}" entryTTL="${xyz.eventid.cache.entry.timetolive}" expirationInterval="${xyz.eventid.cache.expiration.interval}" />
    </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>

    <sub-flow name="mapEventsForListings" doc:name="mapEventsForListings">
        <logger message="Entering mapEventsForListings flow..." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-variable variableName="mapEventsForListingsTimeInMillis" value="#[new java.util.Date().getTime()]" doc:name="Set Entry Time In Millis"/> 
        <foreach doc:name="Map Event ID to each listing">
            <choice doc:name="Choice">
               <when expression="#[payload.getEvent().getVenue().isEmpty() || payload.getEvent().getDate().isEmpty() || payload.getExternalListingId().isEmpty() || payload.getPricePerProduct().getAmount()==0]">
                        <logger message="Missing input data for Payload" level="INFO" doc:name="Listing Missing Data Fields"/>
                        <set-variable variableName="noOfIncompleteListings" value="#[noOfIncompleteListings + 1]" doc:name="Increment Incomplete Listings Error Count"/>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                    <set-variable variableName="ablMapEventToListingParameters" value="/?locale=en_US&amp;venueName=#[payload.getEvent().getVenue()]&amp;eventDateLocal=#[payload.getEvent().getDate()]" doc:name="Autobulk Event Search Parameters"/>
                    <set-variable variableName="originalListingRequest" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
                    <set-payload value="#[null]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                    <ee:cache doc:name="Cache" cachingStrategy-ref="eventIdCachingStrategy">
                        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" connector-ref="HttpsClientConnector" address="${xyz.search.catalog.events.ship.api.url}#[flowVars['ablMapEventToListingParameters']]" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP Outbound Call to BulkCreateListing API">
                            <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound"> 
                                <add-message-property key="TARGET_HOST" value="${target.host}"/>  
                                <add-message-property key="Authorization" value="#[flowVars['shUserBearerToken']]"/>  
                                <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="application/json"/> 
                            </message-properties-transformer>
                        </https:outbound-endpoint>
                        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
                    </ee:cache>
</otherwise>
</choice>
</flow>
```

Value of flowVars['ablMapToListingParameters'] = www.api-dev.xyz.com/search/catalog/events/ship/v3/?locale=en_US&venueName=SAPCenter&eventDateLocal=2015-07-16T20:00

Answer (score 3):

Try with the following config :-

```
<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="cachingStrategy" doc:name="cachingStrategy">
   <managed-store storeName="myNonPersistentManagedObjectStore" maxEntries="-1" entryTTL="20000" expirationInterval="5000"/>
</ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
```

Also, you are setting the payload null before your cache scope ... cache scope require the payload to determine if the response can be cached or not.
For same payload it will make a **cache-hit** and provide the response from cache else it will process the message and store it in cache

ref:- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/cache-scope